# avoid repeated information in Latex

Tags: beamer

I am preparing for a presentation with latex(beamer).
I am using my college theme.
our Professor doesn't want repeated information in the first page.
For example : title and name of the author are shown 2 times up and down in the page.
How  can i avoid the repeat ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}

%Style
\usetheme{bht}


%Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{ifthen,xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage {times}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}



\title{\bf Automation }
\author{\footnotesize Group B}
        
        
\institute[LT]{n}
\date{24 December 2020}


\begin{document}
%titleseite
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
\center{\large\bf- Group B- }
```

Comment: Since we don't have the beamer theme bht we cannot say for sure but you might try `\begin{frame}[plain]\titlepage\end{frame}` to use an empty frame (i.e. without the footline where I guess the name appears again).

Comment: note `\center` is not a latex command it should be `\begin{center}..\end{center}` the form shown woul dcentre all the following text not just the text in `{...}`

Comment: Please add a link to the theme